# Match any one item in a list

Tags: regex, python-3.x, praw

For a reddit bot I want to find comments that match a certain regex plus any word of a list. I got this:

```
wordlist = ["word1", "word2", "word3")
for comment in reddit.subreddit('test').comments(limit = None):
    match = re.findall(r"(?i).*\bTest\b\s" + ANYITEMOFWORDLIST, comment.body)
```

where I want ANYITEMOFWORDLIST to be, well any item of wordlist. What do I use there? It's probably very easy, but I'm not really a programmer. I'm sorry if such a question was asked before, but I couldn't find anything

Answer (score 0):

You would usually match any words from a list of words `[a, b, c]` using alternation: `(?:a|b|c)`. It's also usually better to use word boundaries (`\b`) if your words will consist of only word characters (a to z, 0 to 9 and _):

```
wordlist = ["word1", "word2", "word3"]
for comment in reddit.subreddit('test').comments(limit = None):
    match = re.findall(r"(?i).*\bTest\b\s\b(?:" + "|".join(wordlist) + r")\b", comment.body)
```